# Importing denormalized csv files into production database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks once again. Please find my sample data below.

1. The test data is coming from csv file. The landId is M:M relationships to to Title table.
2. So, there will be only one landId for a specific TitleID but many TitleID can be associated with One landId.
3. There is a bridge table called ##land_title between Title table and land table.
4. Basically, I want to append the records from the csv to existing records in Land table, then insert corresponding values to ##land_title and then to Title table.
5. I was trying this method but I need help from you guys. Hope this make sense.

---

```
 INSERT INTO ##land_title( LandId, titleid, CreatedDateTime, CreatedUserID )
     SELECT LandID, Land_TitleID, getdate(),'xyz'
    FROM #Testdata as sd
 OUTPUT inserted or SCOPE_IDENTITY()


 CREATE TABLE #Testdata
 (
     LandID INT,
     ReferenceID INT,
     Land_TitleID VARCHAR(MAX)
 )
 INSERT #Testdata SELECT 1,  9, '18,20,22'
 INSERT #Testdata SELECT 2,  8, '17,19'
 INSERT #Testdata SELECT 3,  7, '13,19,20'
INSERT #Testdata SELECT 4,  6, ''
INSERT #Testdata SELECT 9, 11, '1,2,3,4'
Select * from #Testdata
;WITH tmp(LandID, ReferenceID, DataItem, Land_TitleID) AS
(
    SELECT
        LandID,
        ReferenceID,
        LEFT(Land_TitleID, CHARINDEX(',', Land_TitleID + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(Land_TitleID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Land_TitleID + ','), '')
    FROM #Testdata
    UNION all
    SELECT
        LandID,
        ReferenceID,
        LEFT(Land_TitleID, CHARINDEX(',', Land_TitleID + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(Land_TitleID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Land_TitleID + ','), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        Land_TitleID > ''
)
SELECT
    LandID,
    ReferenceID,
    DataItem
FROM tmp
ORDER BY LandID
```

Thanks

R

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Your question is lacking of details. What have you tried so far? What technologies/languages are you using? What database engine? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I am using sql server 2012. Not much I have done. I just want an opinion whether this is technically doable. In a nutshell, I have a csv file that was put together joining multiple tables from third party firm. We kind of have similar database table structure. What I am trying to do is to insert or append the csv into production relevant tables.
For example, InterestIds will be appended to Interest table and so on.
Hope this make sense.

Comment: Hello, in SO you should not ask for "opinions"

Comment: CSV files aren't normalized or denormalized. They are flat text files containing lines with fields, each of them having a *single* value. What you posted here is definitely not flat, more like XML or JSON. If you want to load data easily, use one of those formats. Otherwise you'll have to create your own parser that understands this complex custom format

Comment: If you want to do it in SQL, then the [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function will be useful. You also will need to do several passes to insert into different tables or to update tables. This means that you will need to create a stored procedure, as this cannot be done in a single query. Such complex things are easier to solve in the front-end in a modern programming language.

Comment: @Rachael "technically doable" is different from feasible. Are you simply asking if it's *possible*? Or whether it's a *good idea*? If the latter, then this question is off-topic as it's going to be opinion-based. Check out the one-page [tour] for a quick look at what kinds of questions thrive on Stack Overflow.

Comment: _I was trying this method but I need help from you guys_ what actual problem are you having?